# Issue with characters in structures

Tags: c++

I am having an issue with this program. This program is basically about to copy a structure into a `char*` ptr and again copying  it into another `malloc`ed ptr and reading it. The problem is it does not print the last

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

typedef  struct
{
int tableId;
char tableName[30];
int tableHeaderPage; // NOT GETTING PRINTED
}sysTable;
int main()
{
    sysTable record;
    record.tableId=11;
    strcpy(record.tableName,"babyyy");
    record.tableHeaderPage=56;
    char *recChar=(char*)malloc(sizeof(sysTable)+1);
    memcpy(recChar,&record,sizeof(record));
    char *recChar2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(sysTable)+1);
    memcpy(recChar2,recChar,sizeof(record));
    sysTable record2;
    int offset=0;
    memcpy(&record2.tableId,&recChar[offset],sizeof(record2.tableId));
    offset+=sizeof(record2.tableId);
    memcpy(&record2.tableName,&recChar[offset],sizeof(record2.tableName));

    offset+=sizeof(record2.tableName);

    memcpy(&record2.tableHeaderPage,&recChar[offset],sizeof(record2.tableHeaderPage));

    cout<<"\n Record Details\n";
    cout<<"\n table Id: "<<record2.tableId;
    cout<<"\n table Name: "<<record2.tableName;
    cout<<"\n tableHeaderPage: "<<record2.tableHeaderPage; // PROBLEM THIS IS NOT PRINTING PROPERLY.

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Do you get no output at all when printing `tableHeaderPage`, or do you get something that's not what you expected?

Comment: Your program doesn't compile. Can you copy-paste the *precise* program that deomonstrates your problem? See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @Rob - Does it not compile because of OP's attempt at putting `tableHeaderPage` in bold?

Comment: My advice to you, make sure the array is initialized propertly: `memset(record.tableName, 0, sizeof(record.tableName));` Now you know the last element of the array has a null character.

Comment: @TedHopp: The problem is with the *value* of some variable, not with the mechanics of formatting and printing. Could have had `printf` there with the same effect...

Comment: I changed it please check the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are manually incrementing `offset` by the size of the struct fields, but not accounting for field alignment.  The real offset of `tableHeaderPage` will be 2 bytes further than what you are doing, because your array is [30], and `tableHeaderPage` will live aligned at a 4-byte boundary.  It would be much better to use address of fields in your `memcpy` calls instead of trying to manually track offset.

Comment: +1, If you add this before the last memcpy, you can see this: `cout << "offset = " << offset << endl; cout << "actual offset = " << (char*)&(record2.tableHeaderPage) - (char*)&record2 << endl;`  One is 34 and the other is 36.

Comment: Ya but given it as memcpy(&record2.tableName,&recChar[offset],sizeof((char*)&(record2.tableHeaderPage) - (char*)&record2) .. It does not work

Answer (score 0):

You mix address offset calculations; on the one hand &record.field, on the other hand char[offset]. Now in a struct the fields may be aligned to say 4-byte addresses. That will throw in 2 bytes after the tableName field (30 chars -> 32).